# How did Robert Baratheon deteriorate from being a mighty warrior to being a fat drunk?

Tags: game-of-thrones, character-development

Robert defeated Rhaegar Targaryen and was seen as one of the greatest warriors in the Seven Kingdoms according to characters' stories, but I missed any explanation of how he became a fat, drunken, whorer?

Comment: He grew older, he was in an unhappy political marriage, he no longer had to claw his way up so he grew lazy. Sexual activity that would be seen as *youthful high spirits* in a 20-year-old noble become problematic in a 40-year-old king.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105324/how-did-robert-baratheons-character-develop-from-a-fine-warrior-to-the-state-se

Comment: As I understand, the *whorer* part was always there. And he probably enjoyed his food and drink the entire time as well, it's just that being a soldier keeps you in shape and limits how constantly you can be sloppy drunk. When he became king, the requirements of his lifestyle changed - but his vices stayed the same. As he and Ned agreed, he never really adjusted to being king.

Comment: There was no one left to fight.

Comment: There's also a stress factor. As a soldier, he knew what he was doing and he knew there were few others who could match him. As a politician, he's out of his depth and he knows it. That tension takes its toll on his health and pushes him further towards his vices.

Comment: Two ways. Slowly, then quickly.

Comment: @Alec Alameddine  What make you think that there is a deterioration involved in changing fromsomeone committing treason and fighting a civil war and causing death and destruction to a person living in a time of peace and more or less enjoying life and harming relatively few people?  It seems to me to be a process of improvement, not deterioration.

Answer (score 6):

Because at this point he does not care about being a warrior, he does not care about being king, all he cares about is...

> eat[ing], drink[ing], and whore[ing], [his] way to an early grave.

Robert was a warrior at heart, and once there was no one left to fight, he had nothing left to live for...

> I was never so alive as when I was winning this throne, or so dead as now that I've won it.
>
> <sub>Robert Baratheon, *A Game of Thrones, Eddard VII*</sub>

And once you stop, you lose your skill...

> Robert was never the same after he put on that crown. Some men are like swords, made for fighting. Hang them up and they go to rust.
>
> <sub>Donal Noye to Jon Snow, *A Clash of Kings, Jon I*</sub>